# when i try to post new product from localhost get error message

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

Here is my Post API working greet with postman

```
router.post(`/`,  uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req, res) =>{
    const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
    if(!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Category')

    const file = req.file;
    if(!file) return res.status(400).send('No image in the request')
    const fileName = req.file.filename
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;

    let product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,
        brand: req.body.brand,
        price: req.body.price,
        category: req.body.category,
        countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
        isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
    })

    product = await product.save();
    
    if(!product)
    return res.status(500).send('The product cannont be created')
    res.send(product);
})
```

and this my form

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fadein">
    <h2 class="page-header">add new product </h2>
    <!-- <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="" role="alert"></div> -->
    <form #addProductForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="SubmitData(addProductForm)">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name
              <sup class="red">*</sup>
          </label>
          <input required name="name" id="name" #name="ngModel" ngModel type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">description
                <sup class="red">*</sup>
            </label>
            <input required name="description" id="description" #description="ngModel" ngModel type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="richDescription">richDescription
              <sup class="red">*</sup>
          </label>
          <input required name="richDescription" id="richDescription" #richDescription="ngModel" ngModel type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="brand">brand
            <sup class="red">*</sup>
        </label>
        <input required name="brand" id="brand" #brand="ngModel" ngModel type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="price">price
          <sup class="red">*</sup>
      </label>
      <input required name="price" id="price" #price="ngModel" ngModel type="number" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">category
        <sup class="red">*</sup>
    </label>
    <input required name="category" id="category" #category="ngModel" ngModel type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="countInStock">countInStock
      <sup class="red">*</sup>
  </label>
  <input required name="countInStock" id="countInStock" #countInStock="ngModel" ngModel type="number" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="image">image
      <sup class="red">*</sup>
  </label>
  <input required  type="file" name="file" #file="ngModel" [ngModel]  accept="image/*">

</div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Product" [disabled]="!addProductForm.valid">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this from component

```
SubmitData(form: { value:  {
    category: string; name: string; description: string;  brand: string;  richDescription: string;
    price: number; countInStock: number; image: File;
}; }){
    const data = {
      name: form.value.name,
      description: form.value.description,
      richDescription: form.value.richDescription,
      brand: form.value.brand,
      price: form.value.price,
      category: form.value.category,
      countInStock: form.value.countInStock,
      image: form.value.image,
    };


    this.productService.postData(data).subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response);

      });
}
```

product Services

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders , HttpEvent} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from "../models/Product";
import { map, Observable, switchMap, tap } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class ProductService {
  // jsonURL = 'assets/data.json';
  warehouseURL = 'http://localhost:5000/v1/products/';



  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.warehouseURL)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('All: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
      );
  }
  getProduct(_id: string): Observable<Product | any> {
    return this.getProducts()
      .pipe(
        map((products: Product[]) => products.find(p => p._id === _id)
        )
      )
  }

  RemoveProduct(_id: string){
    this.http.delete<Product[]>(this.warehouseURL+ _id)
    .subscribe(()=>{
    })
  }
  postData(data: any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.warehouseURL}`, data)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
    );
  }

}
```

when I try to post using postman it works fine, but I cannot post data from the application it self and generates an error message "400 NO image in the request".So can you guys tell me what my mistake is? thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change image input tag's `name` attribute to `image` instead of `file`, and also, you need to add file listener, and include it to the form upon submit:

```
<input type="file" name="image" #image="ngModel" [ngModel] accept="image/*" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```

Also, you need to prepare `form-data` and send that instead of an object.

```
// file holder
image?: File | any;

// file listener
onFileChange(event: any) {
if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  this.image = file
}
}
```

construct form in the `SubmitData`:

```
   const data = new FormData();

    data.append('name', form.value.name);
    data.append('description', form.value.description);
    data.append('richDescription', form.value.richDescription);
    data.append('brand', form.value.brand);
    data.append('price', form.value.price);
    data.append('category', form.value.category);
    data.append('countInStock', form.value.countInStock);
    data.append('image', this.image);
```

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', url: 'http://localhost:5000/v1/products/', ok: false, …}
error
: 
"No image in the request"
headers
: 
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
: 
"Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/v1/products/: 400 Bad Request"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
400
statusText
: 
"Bad Request"
url
: 
"http://localhost:5000/v1/products/"

Comment: can you include code for `this.productService.postData`

Comment: POST http://localhost:5000/v1/products/ 400 (Bad Request)

SubmitData @ dashboard.component.ts:57
DashboardComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_4_listener @ dashboard.component.html:5

Comment: @NourFares no, I meant the code of the `postData` method, how are you sending it from there

Comment: postData(data: any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.warehouseURL}`, data)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
    );
  }

Comment: <form #addProductForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="SubmitData(addProductForm)">.    are this code have error ?

Comment: @NourFares include the code not in the comments, but in your post by using edit feature

Comment: @NourFares you need to post `form-data`, not object. try the updated code

Comment: after working now don’t accept post requests ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: you didn't provide enough information about the problem, and it's not clear how it is related to the question/answer. from the error, the problem is most likely on the server, where `req.body.name` is `undefined`.?, and most likely the whole body, so try adding validation on the server to not to process requests without body/data and return 400

Comment: Can you write a example please?

Comment: you still didn't provide more information. you need to debug the code step by step and see where is the error. if it's on the server, and `name` is missing, then you can handle it the way you handle `file` and `category`: `if(!req.body.name/or some other field) return res.status(400).send('some error..')`. it doesn't seem to be connected with the initial problem with the file upload..